# Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED while trying to install Node-Red

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, debian-jessie

When i try to install Node-Red with

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
```

i get an Error:

```
GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:644:36)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:100:17)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:275:8)
If you need help, you may report this log at:
    <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
or email it to:
    <npm-@googlegroups.com>

System Linux 3.14.60-fslc-imx6-sr
command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--unsafe-perm" "node-red"
cwd /home/debian
node -v v0.11.7
npm -v 1.3.8

Additional logging details can be found in:
    /home/debian/npm-debug.lgo
not ok code 0
```

Btw. the versions of node and npm seems to be wrong, i have node v10.13.0 and npm 6.4.1
although in the error message it shows something else (?)

Comment: how did you install the updated versions of Node/NPM? If it's via nvm then root (the user running npm after sudo) will not be using the same version.

Comment: It was with nvm, how can I use the new versions?

Comment: To be honest I would work out how to upgrade the system copy of node/npm to something a LOT newer rather than work out how to make nvm work with multiple users

Comment: I thought upgrading it to node v10 and npm 6 would be enough. maybe i should remove it completely and install newest version from the beginning, although that would be much work i guess